# Dataframe comparison slow

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a efficiency problem.

I wrote a project on mac and it ran well. Then I ran the exactly same file and input exactly same data on windows system but it's extremely slow.

After some experiment, I found the bottleneck is wired:

```
    A = B==C
```

Both B and C are huge DataFrames. B and C have the same shape, index and columns. A is filled with boolean values from the comparison of B and C.

It made me confused that it ran well and fast on mac but really slow on windows. Even though I don't think the problem is on CPU or python version, I still put this info and hope someone can give me some hints.

```
    python version on windows:
    3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

    python version on mac:
    3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

**Update**

After more research, I found the problem is on spyder Idle. I ran the file on the default idle the performance was as good as on mac but when I ran it through spyer (or maybe Ipython?) the problem occurred. This finding made me more confusing because I also ran the file on mac through spyder which didn't have this problem. I don't know whether this info helps you guys find out the problem.

Comment: I'll go on record to say... I have no idea why there would be a difference.

Comment: I know! In my experiment, I cut off parts of the project gradually and print out the number of iteration to see the performance. Firstly I didn't expect this line can do huge effect so I cut this line off with some other part. After more tiral I found that when I add this line the performance became extremely bad. Maybe I should try it on another PC with windows.